# Reading from txt ruins formatting

Tags: android

I'm saving some values to a txt file and after that i want to be able to show it in a dialog.All good,done that but though the values in the txt file are formated nicely,like this :

```
Aaaaaaaa       0.55        1
Bbbbb          1           2.2
CCCCCCCCC      3           0.22
```

When reading and setting them to a textview they get all messy like this :

```
Aaaaaaaa      0.55         1
Bbbbb       1           2.2
CCCCCCCCC      3       0.22
```

My writting method :

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        for (int n = 0; n < allpret.size() - 1; n++) {
            if (cant[n] != Float.toString(0)
                    && pret[n] != Float.toString(0)) {
                String myFormat = "%-20s %-5s %-5s%n";
                pw.println(String.format(myFormat, prod[n], cant[n],
                        pret[n]));
```

My reading method :

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
```

Why does it ruin the amount of spaces and how can i fix this ?
Thanks and have a good night !

Comment: Have you tried using the tab `\t` character? Something like this:

`String myFormat = "%-20s\t\t%-5s\t\t%-5s%n";`

Comment: Yes,same thing.The problem is not at writting it but at reading or viewing it.Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two solutions:

1. Try setting the font to monospaced via `textView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE)`.
2. Don't use a single TextView and make a layout with different ones arranged as you need them instead. For example, [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) is very good at such cases and it is available in all Android versions. If you need, you can add rows programmatically, so this is not a problem.

Comment: Great,it fixed it.Why is that ? Please explain if you can,i wish to understand,heh.Thanks !!

Comment: @SorinGrecu The monospaced font? It's because usually fonts have different character width, so if you have a string of, say, 10 characters, nothing guarantees that it's going to be exactly the same width as some other string with 10 characters. Hence the alignment can be totally off. With monospaced fonts, however, all the characters are guaranteed to have the same width, therefore two strings with the same number of characters will always have exactly the same width.